# Setting up sublime build file for sass/scss

Tags: sass, sublimetext2, build-automation

I am trying to set-up automatic build of .scss files in Sublime Text 2.  I keep getting the error `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.  I've tried several configurations, but I'm just not getting it.

On my current project, the structure is like:

```
- 2014
  - sites
    - all 
      - themes
        - 2014sub_theme
          - sass
          - css
```

I have set-up a project and within my .sublime-project file I have (complete file contents):

```
{
  "folders":
    [
      {
        "path": "sites/2014"
      }
    ],
  "build_systems":
    [
      {
          "name": "SASS-Custom",
          "cmd": [
                      "sass", 
                      "--watch", 
                      "sass:css"
                  ],
          "working_dir": "$project_path/sites/2014/sites/all/themes/2014sub_theme"
      }
  ]
}
```

When I save, I get the following error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'sass', u'--watch', u'sass:css']]
[dir:  C:\wamp\www\sites\2014\sites\all\themes\2014sub_theme]
[path: __path stuff removed__]
[Finished]
```

Without a doubt, the `sass` folder is at `C:\wamp\www\sites\2014\sites\all\themes\2014sub_theme\sass` and `css` is at `C:\wamp\www\sites\2014\sites\all\themes\2014sub_theme\css`.

From cmd.exe, I do this:

1. cd C:\wamp\www\sites\2014\sites\all\themes\2014sub_theme
2. sass --watch sass:css

It works just fine, any changes to `sass/global.scss` are immediately compiled to `css/global.css`

I am using SublimeOnSaveBuild.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and spent quite a while messing with it. I know this is very late, probably too late to help you, but I'm going to answer anyway for anyone else who might stumble upon this question.

For some reason, just using "sass" fails from the ST3 build system. Change it to "sass.bat" (also a file in the same directory) and it worked for me.